# How to store blocks in properties in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I'd like to store objective-c block in a property for later use. I wasn't sure how to do it so I googled a bit and there is very little info about the subject. But I've managed to find the solution eventually and I've thought that it might be worth sharing for other newbies like me.

Initially I've thought that I would need to write the properties by hand to use Block_copy & Block_release.

Fortunately I've found out that [blocks are NSObjects](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxUsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH5-SW1) and `- copy`/`- release` is equivalent to `Block_copy`/`Block_release`. So I can use `@property (copy)` to auto generate setters & getters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use Objective-C blocks as properties?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935574/can-i-use-objective-c-blocks-as-properties) This question is more recent than the one there.

Comment: Full example code, UP-TO-DATE, explained simply for beginners: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20760583/294884

Comment: For new readers, this extremely old question is now happily extremely passé.  You just say **@property (copy)void (^doStuff)(void);** with nothing more or less than copy.  nowadys this is explained crystal-clearly (including the why) in a number of places in the apple doco.  it couldn't be simpler; that's the whole answer.  Indeed the whole issue is of only historic value since you now just use Swift.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

**Edit: updated for ARC**

```
typedef void(^MyCustomBlock)(void);

@interface MyClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) MyCustomBlock customBlock;

@end

@implementation MyClass

@end

MyClass * c = [[MyClass alloc] init];
c.customBlock = ^{
  NSLog(@"hello.....");
}

c.customBlock();
```

Comment: Anyone know why for blocks you should use (nonatomic, copy) and not (nonatomic,retain)?  Typically retain is used and I can't find anywhere that explains why to use copy for blocks.

Comment: Yes Dave, really.  I can search also and saw those too.  Explanations were vague like you use copy "to make them actually survive the stack frame."  I figured that retaining the object would also do that.  None explained how blocks are stack allocated.  However, a comment did link to an article - http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/10/how-blocks-are-implemented-and.html that explained it well.  See under "Blocks are slightly weird objects".  So thank you!

Comment: Dave -- I'm not really sure one should use "nonatomic" particularly.  (FWIW - not necessarily correct!!! - the latest greatest Apple doco says you should use "copy" - end of story.)  It's difficult to see that performance could matter, and since your post here is pretty much the world's only reference on the matter, perhaps it's a dangerous thing to have out there. Any thoughts on this obscure issue?  Thanks!

Comment: @JoeBlow you only need atomicity if you're worried about getting and setting the value of the property simultaneously from multiple queues. Otherwise it doesn't matter.

Comment: But Dave, the only possible reason to use "nonatomic" (today) is if (incredibly, for some bizarre reason) you are writing code that you WANT to NOT be safe (for some bizarre reason) if the code is ever used with multiple threads, multiple queues etc. Using "nonatomic" is, essentially, just wrong today. Why would you possibly, ever, want to deliberately make code unsafe? {Sure, set aside absolutely obscure scientific computing situations, etc.} Your word is Law, DDL, I just do whatever you say on here :)  But I don't follow you here .. teach me

Comment: I/we use `nonatomic` everywhere. It should have been default IMO. `atomic` makes for a larger binary, lower performance (locks on all accessors) and it appears to promise thread-safety - when usually that has to be solved at a higher level than property accessors.

Comment: @DaveDeLong What do you think of this answer, which says that, in ARC, a strong reference to a block type is equivalent to Block_copy? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426382/what-is-the-main-difference-using-copy-and-strong-ownership-qualifiers-in-pr

Would you recommend using strong or copy in this case?

Answer (score 104):

Alternatively, without the typedef

`@property (copy, nonatomic) void (^selectionHandler) (NSDictionary*) ;`

Comment: To clarify, as the syntax is so opaque, this is a block property named "selectionHandler" that takes an NSDictionary* argument and returns void.

Comment: I don't think it is so hard to read, but I agree that it looks nicer with the typedef. I tend to write a bunch of typedefs for the parameters I want to usually pass: PFObjectBlock, PFStringBlock, PFArrayBlock, PFErrorBlock, etc.

Comment: would id, SEL, IMP allow further simplifications?

Answer (score 9):

You can find a very good explanation of this in WWDC 2012 session 712 starting in page 83. The correct way of saving a block under ARC is the following:

```
@property(strong) my_block_type work;
```

Be careful with the retain cycles. A good way to solve is set the block to nil when you do not need it anymore:

```
self.work = nil;
```

Comment: only with ARC. Under MRC this is wrong. But `copy` works correctly under both MRC and ARC

Comment: I do not think that copy will work well in all the cases in MRC but maybe in most of them

Comment: You are right with MRC, but it is not in ARC. Sorry, I wanted to say ARC in my previous comment.

Comment: Really interesting, any idea on how ARC manages to move the block out of the stack?

Comment: "__block yourClass* blockSelf = self". Only use blockSelf within the "work" property.