# What is the main difference using "copy" and "strong" ownership qualifiers in property declaration with block types?

Tags: properties, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks

Example #1

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^errorBlock) (NSError *);
```

Example #2

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) void (^errorBlock) (NSError *);
```

I know that blocks are standard variables on stack, and by making a copy we are "moving" them to the heap.

Thats all? Or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no difference. Since the property has a block type, according to http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#blocks

> With the exception of retains done as part of initializing a __strong
>   parameter variable or reading a __weak variable, whenever these
>   semantics call for retaining a value of block-pointer type, it has the
>   effect of a Block_copy.