# iOS: Detect dismissViewControllerAnimated while using UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uimodalpresentationstyle

In my **ViewControllerA**, I try to show **ViewControllerB** by calling:

```
let VC2 = ViewControllerB()
VC2.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext
presentViewController(VC2, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

So the content of **ViewControllerB** is shown on top of **ViewControllerA**.

When pressing a button in **ViewControllerB**, this is called:

```
dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

However, `viewWillAppear` of **ViewControllerA** is not called.

If the line `VC2.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext` is removed, then `viewWillAppear` of **ViewControllerA** is called.

While using `UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext`, `viewWillAppear` of **ViewControllerA** is not called. How to detect if **ViewControllerB** is dismissed in **ViewControllerA** in this situation? I want to run some codes in **ViewControllerA**, but not using `completion` of `dismissViewControllerAnimated` in **ViewControllerB**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you create your own completion block on `ViewControllerB`? You can assign it when you create the instance of `ViewControllerB` on `ViewControllerA`, then you can just call that when you call `dismissViewControllerAnimated` on `ViewControllerB`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, I am unfamiliar with completion blocks. I have spent a few hours searching online but still can't figure out what to do. Can you please show me an example or some hints where I should start? Many thanks!

Comment: There are plenty of answers here on SO that should help you :)
Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16324095/custom-completion-block-for-my-own-method) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081831/how-to-store-blocks-in-properties-in-objective-c)

Comment: Thank you for the links in Objective-C. They helped me to understand completion blocks. Now I have got a solution in Swift. [Here](http://studyswift.blogspot.tw/2015/11/using-completion-block-to-detect.html) is it as well as some references.

Comment: @ehhhuang You're welcome! Glad you got your issue sorted. Care to accept my answer?

Comment: Your answer is really helpful to me. I just learned what "accept answer" means in SO. :)