# Are Objective-C blocks autoreleased?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

If I declare a block like this `^{ DoSomething; }` and put it in an instance variable, do I need to `Block_copy()` if I'm going to keep it around?

Comment: Note .. for ARC, some example code is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20760583/294884

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you need to copy. Not because they are autoreleased, but because they start on the stack. Note that blocks also behave like regular Objective-C objects, so that you can copy them using the regular `copy` message:

```
void storeBlockForLater: (dispatch_block_t) block
{
    [someArray addObject:[[block copy] autorelease]];
}
```

Or, if you have a block property:

```
@property(copy) dispatch_block_t block;
```

Retaining does not help here.

Comment: Thanks, I also found this great article on the subject: http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/10/how-blocks-are-implemented-and.html

Comment: Yup;  and if you use `copy`, use `release`.   If you you use `Block_copy()`, use `Block_release()`.  Don't mix 'em.

Comment: @bbum Is it safe to use `Block_copy()` and `autorelease`? Should you only use `autorelease` with `copy`?

Comment: @openfrog: You still need to copy the block, but that’s all. You don’t have to – and can’t – release nor autorelease it.