# Is it possible to obtain an intermediate C code from Objective-C?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, runtime

As I understand correctly, besides the fact that Objective-C language is a strict superset of a "clean" C, added OOP paradigm is simulated by a set of functions partially described in [Objective-C Runtime Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html).

Therefore, I'm expecting a possibility to somehow compile Objective-C code in an intermediate C/C++ file (maybe with some asm inserts).

Is it generally possible ?

Comment: Possible? Propably. Practical? Propably not.

Comment: If we use -rewrite-objc, will rewritten C++ source code uses objective-c runtime library? I mean selectors, messages, objc-msgSend function and others?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the clang rewriter to convert to C++. Not aware of a way to go to C though.

The rewriter is available via the "-rewrite-objc" command line option.

Comment: Thanks, C++ could be also an option! Going to check that.

Comment: The rewriter is a start, but if any of your classes inherit from NSObject (and other classes) and use their functionality, converting your source isn't going to do much good.

Comment: @Catfish_Man: seems that clang's "-rewrite-objc" option is something undocumented. Could you please point me to some resources with explanation (if they exist) ?

Comment: @bbum: yes, I'm expecting some kind of great complexity. But I hope that this will, at least, minimize my porting effort.

Comment: Honestly, it probably won't.  At least, it *may* help at the data layer, depending on how it is architected, and will certainly not help at all with anything UI related.  This assumes that your app is cleanly layered (which few ever are :).

Comment: "cleanly layered" ? In my dreams maybe :)

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't expect this to be a "good" option. More of an "option of last resort".

Comment: @Catfish_Man will rewritten C++ source code uses objective-c runtime library? I mean selectors, messages, objc-msgSend function and others?

Comment: if in my obj-c code, where was written method - (void)doSomething:(NSString*)parameter , will it be rewritten as objc_msgSend(obj, "doSomething", parameter); ?

Comment: Yes, the rewritten code still depends on having an objc runtime available

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no software that preprocesses Objective-C code into intermediate C code.

But you could write your Objective-C program entirely in C by calling directly into the Objective-C runtime. The trouble is just that the code might vary between implementations or even different versions of the same runtime.

The question is, is it actually worth the trouble?

Comment: I already have a project written in Obj-C, and now I have to port some portion of existing code to C/C++ for another platform.

Comment: Have you checked if the other platform has an Objective-C runtime available? For Linux/BSD/etc. there is [GNUstep](http://www.gnustep.org/); you could also try [Cocotron](http://www.cocotron.org/) which has Windows support and offers Obj-C 2.0 features.