# Compiling Objective-C into runtime form?

Tags: objective-c, c, compilation, messaging, objective-c-runtime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to obtain an intermediate C code from Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900838/is-it-possible-to-obtain-an-intermediate-c-code-from-objective-c)

How can I take an Objective-C source (.m) and compile it into its raw runtime form?

```
e.g [(id)target performSelector:(SEL)selector withObject:(id)obj];
```

to

```
objc_msgSend(target, @selector(selector), obj);
```

Comment: Why would you want to? You cannot directly translate all objc method calls to `msgSend*` variants, due to function pointers needing to be castes to the proper types first.

Comment: Obvious answer: By using an Objective-C compiler?

Comment: @duskwuff I think that's what he wants to do, just to look at what the intermediary step looks like, but there doesn't seem to be any documented flag in gcc or clang to output the C source.

Comment: I'm asking how to invoke it in the compiler. Hence the reason I used the term compile.

Comment: I don't think the intermediate C source exists. The Objective-C syntax is not handled particularly differently from C; it's converted directly to a compiler intermediate representation.

Comment: I'm asking, "How you can ask the compiler to export the intermediate C representation of a given Objective-C class?"