# Block Declaration Syntax List

Tags: objective-c, syntax, objective-c-blocks

Block syntax in Objective C (and indeed C, I presume) is notoriously incongruous. Passing blocks as arguments looks different than declaring blocks as ivars, which looks different than `typedef`ing blocks.

Is there a comprehensive list of block-declaration syntax that I could keep on hand for quick reference?

Comment: What's wrong with ["Declaring and Creating Blocks"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxDeclaringCreating.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH4-SW1) in the Blocks Programming Topics Guide?

Comment: straightforward explanation of using block properties: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20760583/294884

Answer (score 700, accepted):

### List of Block Declaration Syntaxes

Throughout, let

- `return_type` be the type of object/primitive/etc. you'd like to return (commonly `void`)
- `blockName` be the variable name of the block you're creating
- `var_type` be the type object/primitive/etc. you'd like to pass as an argument (leave blank for no parameters)
- `varName` be the variable name of the given parameter

And remember that you can create as many parameters as you'd like.

#### Blocks as Variables

Possibly the most common for of declaration.

```
return_type (^blockName)(var_type) = ^return_type (var_type varName)
{
    // ...
};
```

#### Blocks as Properties

Much like declaring blocks as variables, however subtly different.

```
@property (copy) return_type (^blockName) (var_type);
```

#### Blocks as Parameters

Note that this is distinct from "Blocks as Arguments"; in this instance, you're declaring a method that wants a block argument.

```
- (void)yourMethod:(return_type (^)(var_type))blockName;
```

#### Blocks as Arguments

Note that this is distinct from "Blocks as Parameters"; in this instance, you're calling a method that wants a block argument with an anonymous block. If you have already declared a block variable, it is sufficient to pass the variable name as the argument.

```
[someObject doSomethingWithBlock: ^return_type (var_type varName)
{
    //...
}];
```

#### Anonymous Block

This is functionally an anonymous block, however the syntax for assigning blocks to variables is simply to set the variable equal to an anonymous block.

```
^return_type (var_type varName)
{
    //...
};
```

#### `typedef` Block

This allows you to set up a short name that can be referenced just like any other class name during the declaration of blocks.

```
typedef return_type (^blockName)(var_type);
```

To then later use `blockName` instead of the standard block declaration syntax, simply substitute.

#### Inline Block

This is arguably a less useful utilization of blocks, but may have its place nonetheless. An inline block is an anonymous block called immediately after instantiation.

```
^return_type (var_type varName)
{
    //...
}(var);
```

Inline blocks are primarily useful for scope offsetting, and are roughly equivalent to simple brace-delimited chunks of code.

```
{
   //...
}
```

#### Recursive Blocks

This allows you to call a block from itself, creating a loop that can be used during callbacks and GCD calls. This instantiation method is free of retain cycles in ARC.

```
__block return_type (^blockName)(var_type) = [^return_type (var_type varName)
{
    if (returnCondition)
    {
        blockName = nil;
        return;
    }

    // ...
} copy];
blockName(varValue);
```

#### Returning Blocks

A method can return a block,

```
- (return_type(^)(var_type))methodName
{
    // ...
}
```

as can a function, if a bit strangely.

```
return_type (^FunctionName())(var_type)
{
    // ...
}
```

### Addendums

If I've missed anything, please let me know in comments, and I'll research/add them.

### Oh, and in Swift...

```
blockName = (varName: var_type) -> (return_type)
```

It's almost like it's a language feature.

Comment: @pcperini A great list! And how to use typedef'd block definition in variable declaration (1st item in your list)? Logical ```BlockType ^blockVar = Anonymous Block``` shows syntax error, without ^ too :(

Comment: Somehow my brain is incapable of remembering all these various syntax for block declarations. I probably look at this answer once a week. Wish I could give you 10 upvotes for this.

Comment: We need a StackOverflow Hall of Fame for answers like this.

Comment: I've converted this into Markdown for use with a viewer for printing. Handy! https://gist.github.com/swizzlr/6268955

Comment: Blocks as return types (from objective-c methods, from C functions, and from other blocks) are missing from this.

Comment: @MarkAmery I cannot seem to nail the syntax for returning a block from another block without a `typedef`. Any help you could lend here would be phenomenal!

Comment: @MarkAmery So funny... I did the same thing.. and THEN noticed you had doe it already!  D'oh!  https://gist.github.com/6858475

Comment: I think I need this as a tattoo.

Comment: If you use this often, like Ben (einsteinx2), I would suggest copying it to a text file somewhere and enclosing the variables in "<#" and "#>" so that Xcode treats them as placeholders when you copy and paste them.  --Rob in Pittsburgh

Comment: Hi pcperini! In your fine example **"Blocks as Parameters"**.  Say I then have a method +(void)blah:(return_type(^)(var_type))after ... how do I then set self.blockName = after ... ?  It doesn't seem to work.  This is in a normal modern ARC setting.  THANKS!

Comment: @JoeBlow what doesn't work about it? Compiler error? Runtime error? Gonna need a bit more info :)

Comment: hi PC!  You know, I did get it working.  But, I suggest you include an example of that in your section "Blocks as Parameters"!  For your millions of fans on this answer!  :)  FOr anyone struggling with this, I put a full example here .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935574/can-i-use-objective-c-blocks-as-properties/20760583#20760583  Because this has **changed a lot over the years in the Xcode milieu** there is a lot of out-of-date information on it. Thank goodness for your answer here, pcperini.  Merry Christmas 2013.

Comment: I found myself using inline block syntax, so I thought I'd contribute one scenario where it's useful: reducing redundancy in switch statements. Instead of `switch (value) { case 1: _someTextField.stringValue = @"one"; break; case 2: ... }`, I have `_someTextField.stringValue = ^NSString *(){ switch (value) { case 1: return @"one"; case 2: ... } }();`. Each case line gets a lot shorter, and if I want to change what I'm doing with the different values (e.g. using attributed strings instead), I only have to do it in one place.

Comment: This is pure GOLD!

Answer (score 87):

I personally like using this website (http://fuckingblocksyntax.com). The name is easier to remember than the block syntax itself:

### http://fuckingblocksyntax.com

and if you can't load URLs with bad words in them you can use this mirror: http://goshdarnblocksyntax.com

[image: fuckingblocksyntax website]

Comment: perfect name for the website.. :D

Answer (score 41):

Typedef:

```
typedef void (^block)(NSString *arg);
```

Inline:

```
void (^block)(NSString *) = ^(NSString *param) {
  // do something....
};
```

Method:

```
- (void)method:(void (^)(NSString *param))handler
```

Comment: This answer shows that it's not that complicated after all... just 3 different syntaxes to mix and match.

Comment: The accepted answer is just a copy of this answer with unnecessary bloat.

Answer (score 16):

The Xcode 4 snippet library contains templates for block typedefs and inline blocks as variables. They are also available via auto-completion (`typedefblock` and `inlineblock`).

For blocks as arguments to methods, I'd recommend declaring a `typedef` and then simply using that. It makes the code much easier to read.

Answer (score 12):

I wrote a completionBlock for a class which will return the values of a dice after they have been shaked:

1. Define typedef with returnType (`.h` above `@interface` declaration)

   ```
   typedef void (^CompleteDiceRolling)(NSInteger diceValue);
   ```
2. Define a `@property` for the block (`.h`)

   ```
   @property (copy, nonatomic) CompleteDiceRolling completeDiceRolling;
   ```
3. Define a method with `finishBlock` (`.h`)

   ```
   - (void)getDiceValueAfterSpin:(void (^)(NSInteger diceValue))finishBlock;
   ```
4. Insert previous defined method in `.m` file and commit `finishBlock` to `@property` defined before

   ```
   - (void)getDiceValueAfterSpin:(void (^)(NSInteger diceValue))finishBlock{
       self.completeDiceRolling = finishBlock;
   }
   ```
5. To trigger `completionBlock` pass predefined variableType to it 
   (Don't forget to check whether the `completionBlock` exists)

   ```
   if( self.completeDiceRolling ){
       self.completeDiceRolling(self.dieValue);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 7):

```
typedef void (^OkBtnBlock)(id data);
typedef void (^CancelBtnBlock)();

@property (nonatomic, strong) OkBtnBlock okBtnBlock;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CancelBtnBlock cancelBtnBlock;

+ (void)foo:(OkBtnBlock)okBtn andCancel:(CancelBtnBlock)btnCancel;
```

Comment: Would be good to describe the whole process step by step, 
blocks are hard to understand if you are new to ios...

Answer (score 3):

If you need to work back in Xcode 4.2, you can also @synthesize a block declared as a property just like you would with a non block property.  Don't let the block syntax throw you.

If your block property is this:

```
@property (copy) return_type (^blockName) (var_type);
```

Then your @synthesize is this:

```
@property blockName;
```

Cheers.

Comment: Hi, could you please recheck.. I was just trying to follow you.. `@property blockName` is not working. I think it should be `@synthesize blockName;` ? (for synthesizing a block)

Comment: oops... wait you already (indirectly) mentioned that it wont work with xcode 7.