# declaring block with auto

Tags: c++, objective-c, c++11, clang, objective-c-blocks

Can I declare ObjC block with auto?

```
auto fun = ^(int x) { NSLog(@"%d", x); }
fun(5);
```

I cannot work out valid syntax for that.

Comment: I suspect **if** it works, it will only work with Objective-C++, as `auto` means something different in C.

Comment: Apparently there's a different meaning in C++0x, where previous C++ specs used `auto` from C (which is just the default storage type). Unless there's a reason that's out of scope of this question, I would encourage not using `auto` at all in this case, preferring `int (^fun)(int) =`. (As an Objective-C developer, I've never used `auto`, and would likely need to explain it to all my coworkers.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a `;` after the declaration of `fun`. Otherwise, you got the syntax right, and Clang will accept that in `-std=c++11 -fblocks` mode, for C++ or Objective-C++ input. (Note that blocks are actually an orthogonal extension which is not part of Objective-C.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the auto keyword from C++/Objective-C++ is used in objective-C.

As for declaring block variable for your example the following will work in objective-C

```
void(^fun)(int x) = ^(int x) {
NSLog(@"%d",x);
};

fun(5);
```

For more declaration options on block there's a very good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201514/block-declaration-syntax-list)

Answer (score 0):

The auto keyword is a c++11 keyword.  Objective-c is a superset of c not c++ and therefor does not contain the properties of c++, but rather c.  As for objective-c++, I do not believe that clang is up to date on all of the new c++11 features, especially in the compiler that builds objective-c++.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Objective-C is a set of extensions which can be added to either C or C++. Clang has a pretty comprehensive C++11 implementation (only missing a couple of features), and the same compiler is used for C++ and Objective-C++.