# Declaring a method that takes a Block

Tags: objective-c, syntax, objective-c-blocks

I'm trying to figure out how to declare a method that takes a block as an argument and just logs an integer value from the outside scope. Most examples I see are doing this on some Apple API like `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:` but I just want to create my own simple version. This is what I have, which is currently not working:

```
@interface IAViewController ()
+(void)tell2:(void(^)(void)) thisBlock;
@end

...

NSInteger someInt=289456;
[IAViewController tell2:^{
    NSLog(@"what is this? %i", someInt);
}];

// ? how do I make this method signature work
+(void) tell2:(void (^thisBlock)) myInt{
    thisBlock(myInt);
}
```

How can I make the method signature params work correctly to output 289456?

Comment: don't really see that as a dupe, not talking about typedef's here

Comment: Check out Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201514/block-declaration-syntax-list

Comment: It has the correct syntax for declaring a method that has a Block parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare a block type as a parameter to an `Objective-C` method, the identifier of the block is outside the type.  So the syntax looks like this:

```
@interface IAViewController ()
+(void)tell2:(void(^)(void)) thisBlock;
@end

@implementation IAViewController
- (void)someMethod {
    NSInteger someInt=289456;
    [IAViewController tell2:^{
        NSLog(@"what is this? %i", someInt);
    }];
}

+(void) tell2:(void (^)(void))thisBlock {
    thisBlock();
}
@end
```

Comment: ah, ok so first void = no return type, the second is no args and the third part is the block passed in. What does the (^) carat in the middle mean - or is it just syntax for specifying this is a block?

Comment: You are correct, the carrot is just the syntax for declaring a block.  In other cases (like declaring a block variable for example) you would put the blocks name next to the carrot.  It's different here because Objective-C methods always look like `methodSignature:(<type>)<identifier>`, so you don't include the block's identifier with its type.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have the text `myInt` where you should have the block name, and then you are calling a block that takes a void argument with an argument that hasn't been declared anywhere.

You have the method declaration in the `@interface` correct. Use it again in the `@implementation` and discard all reference to `myInt`.

```
+(void)tell2:(void(^)(void)) thisBlock
{
    // your method implementation
}
```