# How to declare a block in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I am declaring this block syntactically it is right still it is throwing error please tell me what i am doing wrong in this declaration.

[image]

Comment: take a look [Block Declaration Syntax List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201514/block-declaration-syntax-list)

Comment: And this has nothing to do with Xcode anyway. (Yes, it's spelled "Xcode", and **not** "xcode").

Comment: Change NSInteger to NSUInteger in your Block Parameters

Comment: Please always copy/paste the (relevant) code and error messages into the question instead of screenshots. That makes it much easier for others to analyze your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Replace Like:

```
[arrToggelButton enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    //Write Your code
}];
```

Happy Coding...

Answer (score 2):

It is not right. The method argument requires a block that takes an unsigned integer (`NSUInteger`), whereas you declared a signed integer argument (`NSInteger`).