# Objective C callbacks with blocks

Tags: ios, objective-c, events, delegates, objective-c-blocks

I have looked at various answers on SO for this but can't quite get my head around how it all actually works.

What I have is a GameEngine that contains touchable elements, what I want is for when an element is touched it fires off a "I have been touched" event that the GameEngine listens for and deals with appropriately.

In C# I'd do this with delegates/events but can't seem to find a decent obj c equivalent that uses blocks. - I want to use Blocks as it more akin to anonymous functions in C# which I am used to.

In C# I'd simply do something like the following, in objective c it seems I need to write a page of code to get the same thing working?

```
touchableObject.touched += (o) => { handler code yay }
```

Edit based on Driis' answer:

**Declaration**

```
typedef void (^CircleTouchedHandler)(id parameter);

@interface CircleView : UIView{
}

@property CircleTouchedHandler Touched;
```

How to call it and pass myself as a parameter?

```
[self Touched(self)]; // this doesnt work
```

Comment: http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2010/7/28/ios4-blocks-1 might be helpful for you.

Comment: show us the page of code you need.

Comment: Why the downvote? Looking at this answer here is seems like a LOT of extra stuff is required, all Im after is the most succinct way of doing it that matches with the way I already do things in other languages http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c

Comment: Or, perhaps a little safer, `if (self.Touched) self.Touched(self);` because if `Touched` is `nil`, you'd crash (because, while you can safely send a message to `nil` (which does nothing), you cannot invoke a `nil` block). Also, you might want to follow [Cocoa property naming conventions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/codingguidelines/Articles/NamingIvarsAndTypes.html), using a lowercase letter, e.g. `touched` instead of `Touched`. Personally, I'd call it something like `touchHandler` or `touchBlock`.

Comment: That property should be `copy`, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Objective-C, that would look something like:

```
touchableObject.touched = ^(id o) { /* handler code */ };
```

Assuming touched is a property of an appropiate block type. If you re-use a block type (think of Func in C#), it makes sense to typedef it, since a block declaration in ObjC tends to become difficult to read very quickly.

The block syntax gets some time to get used to in Objective-C when you are coming from another language with slightly more elegant block/lambda syntax. To learn and as a reference, [see this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9201774/13627), which has helped me a lot.

To typedef a type for touched, you would use something like:

```
typedef void (^Handler)(id parameter);
```

Then simply declare the touched property as type handler.

Comment: This looks promising - How do I define touched?

Comment: How do I actually call the callback? '[self Touched(self)];' doesnt work? (I updated my question based on your feedback)

Comment: Note that unlike C#'s events, this particular implementation allows only a single callback to be registered. You could, however, implement a register method and back it with an array or dictionary of blocks to support multiple callbacks.