# What does (void (^)(BOOL supported)) mean?

Tags: objective-c

as I am working myself into some new code, I came across a thing, where I couldnt find any explanation for in the web so far. So hopefully you can give me one.

I have this method signature in Objective-C code:

```
-(void) supportsUrl: (NSString*) url callback:(void (^)(BOOL supported)) callback;
```

Can someone please tell me what it is about in the last parameter?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html

Comment: See also [Block declaration syntax list](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9201514)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a block that takes a `BOOL` argument and returns `void`. [See the documentation for more info on the syntax.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html)

When invoking this method, you can provide a callback through this block. This will let you submit code to be executed after the method has run.

For example:

```
[self supportsUrl:@"http://www.google.com" callback:^(BOOL supported){
    if (supported) NSLog(@"Yay, supported");
    else NSLog(@"Nay, not supported");
}];
```