# How do I attach a Void -> Void closure to a header file in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I'm updating a legacy app and I want to add a nullable, assignable closure of type `(() -> ())?` to my header file. How do I do this in Objective-C?

Comment: A closure is called a `block` in Objective-C. See there: http://fuckingblocksyntax.com If it's a method closure see the one there: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-presentviewcontroller?language=objc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Block Declaration Syntax List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201514/block-declaration-syntax-list)

Answer (score 0):

In my `.h` file, this is what I was going for:

`@property (nullable, copy) void (^myNullableClosure) (void);`

Then I can assign in my Swift code as:

```
let vc = ViewController()
vc.myNullableClosure = {
    print("something")
}
```

then later in the `ViewController`, I call `myNullableClosure?()`