# What retain policy should be used for a block as an object property?

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks

I have the following initializer:

```
- (id) initWithBlock:(void(^)void) block;
```

and within the initializer I want to assign the block to a property so that it can be executed at a later time.

```
typedef void(^block)(void);
@interface myClass()
@property (X, nonatomic)    block theBlock;
@end
```

What should X be and why? (using ARC)

Comment: I have just taken a look to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935574/can-i-use-objective-c-blocks-as-properties). I'm not sure 100% but maybe `copy` is the best approach.

Comment: `copy` and `strong` are definitely *not* equivalent under ARC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy a block.

If you want details, please see an article by Mike Ash on the topic.  Even if you don't want the details you should read it.

http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-08-14-practical-blocks.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use copy. A block which has not been copied lives on the stack. Retaining something on the stack would be meaningless.