# Xcode 4 automatically generates iVars when using @property,where can I find the official doc for this feature?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, properties, llvm

I have read "What's new in Xcode",but I can't find the official explanation for this feature.
Where can I find the official explanation? Which documentation? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find this in the Apple documentation in [Objective-C Programming Language: Declared Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html) under "Property Implementation Directives". Whether or not an ivar is synthesized automatically depends on what runtime you are using:

> There are differences in the behavior of accessor synthesis that depend on the runtime (see also “Runtime Difference”):
>
> - For the legacy runtimes, instance variables must already be declared in the @interface block of the current class. If an instance variable of the same name as the property exists, and if its type is compatible with the property’s type, it is used—otherwise, you get a compiler error.
> - For the modern runtimes (see “Runtime Versions and Platforms” in Objective-C Runtime Programming Guide), instance variables are synthesized as needed. If an instance variable of the same name already exists, it is used.

iOS always uses the modern runtime so you never need to declare ivars explicitly.

Comment: The link is no longer available.

Answer (score 14):

Assuming you mean that it auto-generates an ivar and getter and setter methods for you even if you omit the `@synthesize`: this is variously called default property synthesis, automatic property synthesis, and property autosynthesis.

There's not a lot of documentation.  As far as I have found, there's **no** official documentation of how it works, just of the fact that it exists.

It's really a clang feature, not an Xcode feature.  It appeared briefly in the version clang shipped with Xcode 4.0 DP 4, but was removed shortly after due to bugs.  It reappeared in the version of clang shipped with Xcode 4.4.  [Here's the commit](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=rev&revision=138913) that added it, I think.

You can find it mentioned in the [Objective-C Feature Availability Index](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012243).

It's also mentioned in the [Clang Language Extensions](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#objc_default_synthesize_properties).

From experimentation:

- If you don't explicitly `@synthesize` a property and it generates an instance variable, it will automatically generate an ivar with the same type (and, under ARC, ownership qualification) as the declared property.  The ivar name will be an underscore (`_`) followed by the declared property name.
- If you **don't** explicitly `@synthesize` a `readonly` property, and you **do** include an explicit getter method, then clang will **not** automatically generate an ivar for you.
- If you **don't** explicitly `@synthesize` a `readwrite` property, and you **do** include **both** an explicit getter and an explicit setter, then again clang will **not** automatically generate an ivar for you.

But I don't know of any official documentation of these behaviors.

Comment: The best documentation I've found is the WWDC 2012 presentation which talked about it a bit.

Comment: Indeed.  The WWDC videos often contain lots of useful info that's not written down in English anywhere public - except maybe in the accompanying slides. :)  The video that discusses default synthesis is [Session 405 - Modern Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/), starting at around 11 minutes.

Comment: This feature, the fact that the `@synthesize` will be generated for you if you don't explicitly declare it yourself, is covered in the document he referenced, the [What's New in Xcode](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011649-SW1). I think he's not focusing on the fact that  `@synthesize` will now be done implicitly for you if you fail to explicitly declare it, but rather the fact that `@synthesize` will generate ivars at all.

Answer (score 2):

This is part of the compiler, actually.

You can read that in the `LLVM` [specification website](http://clang.llvm.org).

Answer (score 1):

I would also draw your attention to the [Coding Guidelines for Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingIvarsAndTypes.html) which advises:

> - Avoid explicitly declaring public instance variables.
>
>   Developers should concern themselves with an object’s interface, not with the details of how it stores its data. You can avoid declaring instance variables explicitly by using declared properties and synthesizing the corresponding instance variable.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with public instance variables.

Comment: @BJHomer Agreed, his question was not exclusively limited to public ivars. But the latter point in this document is relevant because as it is telling you that instance variables will be synthesized. He was looking for official documentation that instance variables will be synthesized, which this text addresses. Furthermore, it provides a little context, the underlying rationale behind letting properties synthesize their ivars.

Comment: iVars are traditionally also public instance variables (since they are publicly accessible no matter where they are declared, and traditionally were always put in the public header since they had to be).