# incompatible blocks type assigning

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks

I have used blocks a few times but never with declaring a typedef first.

I am trying to setup this definitions on a class (lets call it ClassA)

```
typedef void (^myBlock)();

@property (nonatomic, copy) myBlock onCompletion;
```

Then I create an instance of the object this class represents and do this:

```
ClassA *obj = [[ClassA alloc] init];
obj.onCompletion = ^(){
   // my code here
};
```

it is complaining "incompatible block pointer types assigning"...

can you guys explain?

Comment: Does "// my code here" contain a return statement? It would change the block type if you return anything;

Comment: Try changing your typedef to `typedef void (^myBlock)(void);`.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe If it were simply `return;` it would be OK.

Comment: @rmaddy That's what I meant with "anything", but you're right, it wasn't clear. So: Does your code contain a return statement with a value?

Comment: Other than return type, both block types are identical and should match.

Comment: @maddy, I thought that by leaving it blak would be void...  please add your comment as an answer, so I can accept... thanks

Comment: @DesperateDeveloper No, leaving it out means the compiler figures out the return type automatically. So if you return something, that will be the type.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe We are talking about the block parameters, not the return value. See my first comment under this question.

Comment: @rmaddy Oh, right, sorry.

Comment: For me the code you posted works fine (as long as the block does not return anything).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the request of the OP I am posting my original comment as an answer even though there are other answers stating the same thing:

You need to clearly specify that the block takes no parameters. Your typedef should be:

```
typedef void (^myBlock)(void);
```

Comment: I thought that by leaving it blank it would be void, but I was wrong. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think when you declare a block or function with empty parentheses (instead of an explicit `void`), the compiler assumes a single `int` parameter.

Comment: @DesperateDeveloper Are you sure this is the full answer to the problem. For me the code you posted works fine, as long as the block does not return a thing.

Comment: @rmaddy The C standard says that a function with no explicit parameters takes an unspecified number of parameters. They will just not be checked by the compiler.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe I knew I fuzzy on that detail. Either way it is different from no parameters.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes. I'm feeling a bit uncomfortable with this solution because I can't reproduce the problem like this. Only the one I pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

Although you don't have to specify the return type of a block, you **must specify** `void` if your block doesn't take any parameters.

Comment: Here's a very useful thing for everyone .. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20760583/294884

Answer (score 1):

Check out this link for block reference: [block syntax](http://fuckingblocksyntax.com/)

Just guessing it might be because you left the block parameter type blank.

```
typedef void (^myBlock)(void); //Untested
```

Answer (score 0):

The only difference in the declared block type `myBlock` and the type of the block literal *might* be the return type.

If you leave the return type out in a block literal the compiler figures it out automatically:

```
myBlock block1 = ^() { // everything is fine
   return;
};

myBlock block2 = ^() { // does not work, types differ
   return 1;
};
```