# How to declare a block with arguments in swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks, swift

Having a hard time figuring out how to properly declare/use blocks with swift. 
What would be the swift equivalent of the following code?

Thanks.

```
^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
if (!user) {
    NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
} else if (user.isNew) {
    NSLog(@"User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
} else {
    NSLog(@"User logged in through Facebook!");
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does Apple's new programming language Swift handle blocks and asynchronous requests?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006398/how-does-apples-new-programming-language-swift-handle-blocks-and-asynchronous-r)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The equivalent of Objective-C blocks are swift closures, so it would go as follows

```
{ (user: PFUser, error: NSError) in
  if (!user) {
    println("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
  } else if (user.isNew) {
    println("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
  } else {
    println("User logged in through Facebook!");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You have many ways offered to pass a block equivalent to function in Swift.

I found three.

To understand this I suggest you to test in playground this little piece of code.

```
func test(function:String -> String) -> String
{
    return function("test")
}

func funcStyle(s:String) -> String
{
    return "FUNC__" + s + "__FUNC"
}
let resultFunc = test(funcStyle)

let blockStyle:(String) -> String = {s in return "BLOCK__" + s + "__BLOCK"}
let resultBlock = test(blockStyle)

let resultAnon = test({(s:String) -> String in return "ANON_" + s + "__ANON" })


println(resultFunc)
println(resultBlock)
println(resultAnon)
```

Update: There are 2 special cases to the Anonymous function.

The first is that function signature can be inferred so you don't have to rewrite it.

```
let resultShortAnon = test({return "ANON_" + $0 + "__ANON" })
```

The second special case works only if the block is the last argument, it's called *trailing closure*

Here is an example (merged with inferred signature to show Swift power)

```
let resultTrailingClosure = test { return "TRAILCLOS_" + $0 + "__TRAILCLOS" }
```

Finally:

Using all this power what I'd do is mixing trailing closure and type inference (with naming for readability)

```
PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions(permissions) {
    user, error in
    if (!user) {
        println("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
    } else if (user.isNew) {
        println("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
    } else {
        println("User logged in through Facebook!")
    }
}
```

IMO it's more beautiful than in ObjC

Comment: Hey @Fran .. you may be able to provide a more up-to-date answer to THIS question ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/20760583/294884  thanks!  you're pretty much it for "expert in SWIFT blocks..."  :)

Comment: Thanks you. I'll send this answer just for information even if the question is for objC.

Comment: ...and IMHO, if you'd used the `__FUNCTION__` that would have been more beautiful.

Answer (score 2):

Critically, if `user` can be `nil` then it **must be** declared as an Optional.  Thus:

```
{ (user: PFUser?, error: NSError) -> {} in
         if (nil == user) ...
    }
```

noting that the type for `user` includes `?` to indicate that `user` is an *optional argument* (either `nil` or of type `PFUser`).

Other answers, that don't use an Optional, won't even compile.

Answer (score 2):

See if this works for you. It's crazy trying to learn this on day two.

```
let afterSignInAttempt: (PFUser?, NSError) -> Void = { user, error in
    if(!user){
      NSLog("Uh oh.")
    } else {
      user.isNew ? NSLog("Signed up") : NSLog("User Logged in")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store block in a variable and call it later, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24604820/1996294)

Answer (score 0):

// define it

```
class IDDBlockTime {
    // return time elapsed in milliseconds
    //
    static func timeSpent(_ block: (Void) -> Void) -> TimeInterval {
        let methodStart = Date()

        block()
        return Date().timeIntervalSince(methodStart) * 1000.0
    }
}
```

// use it

```
    let timeSpent = IDDBlockTime.timeSpent {
        // lines of code you want to measure
        //
        self.doSomethig()
    }

    print("timeSpent: '\(timeSpent) ms'")
```