# Properties return nil when a UIViewController is not being presented

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller

If `ViewController1` is not being presented but `ViewController2` is: I can easily update GUI in `ViewController1` from `ViewController2` but I cannot retrieve any values in `ViewController1` while `ViewController2` is presented. When `ViewController1` is not being presented it always returns properties as nil.

In my case, each view controller is being presented on a tab bar view controller.

What would be the best way to go about solving this?Thank you.

Comment: what's relationship between vc1 and vc2. Your question is sort of unclear.

Comment: Check  the referencing chain you set, you can update viewcontroller1 even it is under the vewcontroller2

Comment: @LucasHuang More of a general question but each view controller is on a tab bar view controller. When one is presented the other is dismissed. The dismissed view controller returns null for its properties when it is dismissed.

Comment: @JasonNam I know I can update one view controller from the other that isn't the problem here. The problem is getting the value of a property from the view controller that is not currently being presented. It returns nil unless it is presented.

Comment: how did you instantiate your view controller, segueing from storyboard or programmatically create from nib file?

Comment: @LucasHuang each view controller class has a class method that returns the instance of the view controller that currently exists.

Comment: Inside the class method, how did you create your view controller. I assumed you use nib file because the view controller is not fully created in that case.

Comment: @LucasHuang I created it in Main.storyboard but the instance of the actual view controller is being stored as a static variable in the class.

Comment: might you have to use Block on presenting viewController. i think you will find your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24603559/store-a-closure-as-a-variable-in-swift/31487182#31487182

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The nib file you specify is not loaded right away. It is loaded the
>   first time the view controller's view is accessed. If you want to
>   perform additional initialization after the nib file is loaded,
>   override the viewDidLoad method and perform your tasks there.

This is from documentation regarding to `initWithNibName` designated initializer :https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/initWithNibName:bundle:

**EDIT** based on the comment from :

If you are using `UITabBarController`, it has a `viewControllers` property so that all retain count of your view controllers is not decreased to 0 which have not been deallocated. If you found anything `nil`, then it should be some problems in your initializers.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBarController/viewControllers

You should not have your own mechanism to access view controllers. Instead, use `viewControllers` property from `UITabBarController` because it helps managing valid view controllers.

Comment: I know but the view has already been accessed and viewDidLoad has already been executed.

Comment: Turns out my class method returning the instance for the view controller was nil but when I use the tab bar view controller to get it it works fine because it continues to store that instance. Thanks!

Comment: See my last paragraph, you should use `UITabBarController` to manage your valid view controllers. If you need to use yours, you have to be very careful how to make it parallel in both your mechanism and `UITabBarController`.