# Store a block object in objective C

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I want to store the completion block object to another block object of my following function

```
- (void)downloadCompletedWithompletion:(void (^)(BOOL success,id responseObject, NSError *error))completion
{
}
```

Can anybody suggest me the syntax of block object to store the completion

Comment: can you explain in detail, what you wan to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your block a name as:

```
typedef void (^ YOUR_BLOCK_NAME)(BOOL success, id responseObject, NSError * error);
```

And then store as any other property:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy, readwrite) YOUR_BLOCK_NAME block;
```

You can create block as:

```
YOUR_BLOCK_NAME block = ^(BOOL success, id responseObject, NSError * error) {};
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20760583/294884